# Query data between two dates in sqlite database with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have NAME (Text) and DATE (Integer) fields in sqlite database. Dates in the DATE field are in the format "dd.MM.yyyy". I could not query between these two dates by selecting dates from DatetimePicker1 and DatetimePicker2 in the form.

the code i use :

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Public Class Form1
    Private CON As SQLiteConnection
    Private DA As SQLiteDataAdapter
    Private DT As DataTable
    Dim QUERY As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        QUERY = "SELECT * FROM [DATA] WHERE Format([DATE],'dd.MM.yyyy') Between " & CDbl(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")) & " And " & CDbl(DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")) & ""
        CON = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=PERSON.sqlite;Version=3;")
        CON.Open()
        DA = New SQLiteDataAdapter(QUERY, CON)
        DT = New DataTable
        DA.Fill(DT)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DT.DefaultView
        CON.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CON = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=PERSON.sqlite;Version=3;")
        CON.Open()
        QUERY = "Select [ID],[NAME],Format([DATE],'dd.MM.yyyy') as DATES From [DATA]"
        DA = New SQLiteDataAdapter(QUERY, CON)
        DT = New DataTable
        DA.Fill(DT)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DT.DefaultView
        CON.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will want to use parameters instead of string concatenation, which may resolve your problem by defining the values. The other reason is to protect against SQL injection attacks (what if someone puts something other than a date in the Date text box?). Otherwise, you probably need single quotes around your dates in the `SQL` string.

Comment: I'd suggest to read this: [https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/)

Comment: Also please review your question before posting. Do you see the extra `"` making everything text? I would fix it but it seems you left off some code. Also there is no point in adding `**` around the Sub declaration. Just make it look nice, please?

Comment: Hi, I have corrected my code. Could you please tell me what you mean by writing sample code?